# Xcode not automatically adding CloudKit containers

Tags: swift, icloud, cloudkit

I have added cloudkit to an existing app and I'm having a little trouble with xcode not automatically creating Containers when adding iCloud capability to Signing & Capabilites. It looks like this:

[image]

What can be the problem here? I have followed the guide on Apples page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit

And when archiving the app I get the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by creating a new container in xcode, quite simple. And now everything works! Just press the plus as seen below and give it a name, preferably same name as the bundle identifier but starting with icloud: icloud.com.developerName.projectName

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to enable iCloud for your provision profile. It can be done by going to the Identifiers section at developer.apple.com. Then find your bundle identifier and make sure iCloud is checked.

[image]

Comment: It was already enabled when I looked it up. But it didn't show any containers, it's zero for the moment